# AccessViolationException when accessing memory from native DLL

Tags: c#, .net

**Summary:**

I wrote a small game engine in assembler and I use the exported functions from my engine DLL in a class of my C# project via DllImport. Everything is working fine so far, however I keep getting an *AccessViolationException* when executing my LoadTexture function.

It's meant to load textures via the .NET Frameworks Bitmap class and pass the address of the first pixel data (mybitmap.Scan0) to my native DLL, which then renders my textures. However, as soon as the native code tries to access data from this memory address, I get the *AccessViolationException*.

This is how my DllImport code of this function looks like:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("engine.dll", 
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
    CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall, 
    ExactSpelling = true), 
    System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity
]
private static extern void LoadTexture(int width, int height, IntPtr handle);
```

And this is the C# code which calls my native function:

```
public static void LoadTexture(string file)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);

    BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 
    bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    LoadTexture(data.Width, data.Height, data.Scan0);
}
```

**Questions:**

- Could there be a mistake in my DllImport statement or does it seem to be alright?
- What else could be the cause of this problem?

If you require further infos which might help solving my question please don't hesitate to ask me in the comments.

Comment: You wrote *assembly code* and think the [DllImport] may cause the problem?  You'll need to debug this.

Comment: Well my asm code works fine if I import libpng and just load my texture with this library (without any C# code at all), but as for now I'd love to load the textures with the .net framework instead since it supports really many different formats. I worked on asm decoders for a few basic image formats too but I don't consider them stable enough yet.

Comment: When I get AVEs I can't track down I fire up [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948) and attach WinDbg. That way, if it's my C++ code segfaulting, WinDbg will break at the offending code.  If it's not my code, then most likely the DllImport is wrong and I use the [MDAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163606.aspx) to help out (like PInvokeStackImbalance).

Comment: Many thanks for you comment but I'm afraid the Application Verifier only works with C++ code. I'll have a closer look at the MDAs, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you locked the texture bitmap into memory?  You need to use`Bitmap.LockBits()` before playing with pointers.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry about forgetting to post the part of my C# code which calls the native function (Yes I call LockBits before calling my native function). I tried two approaches so far, using the ReadOnly and the ReadWrite lock mode, but unfortunately I wasn't successful yet.

Comment: Oh well.  I have to suggest that your LoadText function is mis-behaving.  Could the format of the scan line returned by Scan0 be different from what it is expecting.  Is it taking into account the Stride and PixelFomat, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx

Comment: Silly me! I changed the project type from AnyCPU to x86 and it works flawlessly now... Took me days to figure that out. Many thanks for investigating my question!